# Converting Fast Delegate to std function

Tags: c++, c++11, std

i'm trying to convert FastDelegate into a std::function, but am having trouble understanding the syntax.

this is the delegate library:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

and the code i'm trying to convert:

```
typedef shared_ptr<IEventData> IEventDataPtr;  
typedef fastdelegate::FastDelegate1<IEventDataPtr> EventListenerDelegate;

//some code to find the event

EventListenerDelegate listener = (*it);  
listener(pEvent); // call the delegate
```

So far this can't work:

```
typedef std::function<std::shared_ptr<IEventData>> Functor;
Functor listener = (*it);
listener(pEvent); // call the delegate
```

Comment: Should be something like `std::function<IEventDataPtr ()>`

Comment: It needs to have a shared_ptr in tho?

Comment: Ok then this: `std::function<std::shared_ptr<IEventData> ()>`

Comment: Not sure how shared ptr is supposed to be a runnable function? That doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, sorry, seems like that fast delegate has no return type. So then it should be `std::function<void(IEventDataPtr)>`.

Comment: `FastDelegate1` seems to be a void function with one parameter, which is `IEventDataPtr`.

Comment: That doesn't work with pure abstract functions, so i can't have it defined that way

Comment: I think that's as close as you will get with `std::function`. Take a look at `std::bind` as well.

Comment: Not what i'm trying to achieve tho

Comment: I think `std::function` and either `std::bind` or a lambda can do whatever the fast delegate can.

Comment: care to explain how to use that in the above example?

Comment: What type is `*it` in your example? What exactly is supposed to happen in `listener(pEvent)` call - what is being delegated to what else? What "doesn't work with pure abstract functions", and in what way does "that" fail to work (e.g. if you get compiler errors, show your code and the text of the message)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be a complete answer as I'm not entirely sure what the fastDelegate library is support to do other than offer the callback functionality.
The original code there comes from Game Coding Complete by Mike Shaffry & Dave Graham.

So I may be missing the part where the books says the fastDelegate Library can attach member variables. So since you have a void function with IEventData as a parameter, all your callback functions will be the same.

```
    typedef std::function<void(IEventData)> Functor;
    Functor listener = (*it);
    listener(pEvent);
```

Then defined somewhere else in your solution would be the actualy "Functor" which is just a typedef for std::function. Such as:

```
   void GameCode::DelegateFunction(IEventData){
   //do stuff with event
   }
```

That's pretty much the gist of how it works. I know this post is old but I figured I'd answer anyways since I was just figuring it out at 4 am myself